# how to do css keyframe animation using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

Basically I have the following css animation which I call it with `$(element).css({'animation': 'glowing 2000ms 1'});`:

```
@keyframes glowing{
    0% { box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0px #001bae; }
    50% { box-shadow: 0 0 6px 2px #001bae; }
    100% { box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0px #001bae;}
}
```

I want to do the same but purely using jquery animate(), can someone help me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it – I would just create a new class containing this animation and then add and remove it with JavaScript.

```js
// Add class and play animation

document.querySelector(".element").classList.add("glow");
```

```css
.glow {
 animation: glowing 2000ms 1;
}


@keyframes glowing {
    0% { box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0px #001bae; }
    50% { box-shadow: 0 0 6px 2px #001bae; }
    100% { box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0px #001bae;}
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```